# Python 2.7, add a dash before the last two digits of a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7, I want to add a dash before the last two digits of a string, only if string is all numeric.

For example:

1234567 **becomes** 12345-78

12345TT **no change**

12345PP678 **no change**

ABCDEFGH **no change**

Comment: miracle `1234567 becomes 12345-78` , how?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a regex to see if a string is all digits, you could use `str.isdigit`, if it is all digit, slice and add a "-",if not leave as is:

```
s = "1234578"

s ="{}-{}".format(s[:-2],s[-2:]) if s.isdigit() else s
print(s)
12345-78
```

It is also more efficient than using a regex.

```
In [16]: s = "1234578" * 1000

In [17]: r= re.compile(r'^(\d*)(\d{2})$')

In [18]: timeit r.sub(r'\1-\2',s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 459 µs per loop

In [19]: timeit "{}-{}".format(s[:-2],s[-2:]) if s.isdigit() else s
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.7 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `1234567` to become `12345-67`

```
re.sub(r'^(\d*)(\d{2})$', r'\1-\2', s)
```